# Is there a data dump command for Solr or a way to iterate through each document in the index?

Tags: lucene, solr

I need to copy my Solr index into PosgreSQL for another project.  Is there an easy way to dump the index into a plain text file (something like pg_dump) or to iterate through each primary key so I can download them one by one?

Answer (score 6):

Solr supports a [CSV output format](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CSVResponseWriter). But note that only [stored fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options) can be returned.